# When to use sync.Mutex with net/http and gorilla/mux

Tags: go

As far as I know, the net/http package uses goroutines for the handlers. Is it necessary that I lock even a map with `sync.Mutex` in order to prevent possible bugs in the `nextId` function cause the function could count an old state of the map?

Here is my example code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
)

var testData = map[int]string {
    1: "foo",
    2: "bar",
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/data", getData).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/data", addData).Methods("POST")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}

func getData(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    for k, v := range testData {
        fmt.Fprintf(writer, "Key: %d\tValue: %v\n", k, v)
    }
}

func addData(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    if data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body); err == nil {
        if len(data) == 0 {
            writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        id := nextId()
        testData[id] = string(data)
        url := request.URL.String()
        writer.Header().Set("Location", fmt.Sprintf("%s", url))
        writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)

    } else {
        writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
}

func nextId() int {
    id := 1

    for k, _ := range testData {
        if k >= id {
            id = k + 1;
        }
    }

    return id
}
```

Comment: Any concurrent access to testData **must** be protected by a mutex. Dead simple.

Comment: @Volker Just for editing/creating data or also when I simply read it like I did in the nextId function?

Comment: @Dagivo If there's a goroutine that ever writes it concurrently, you also have to protect reads. Period.

Comment: @Dagivo think there is not much ambiguity in "**must**": Must is must. You must understand that you do not read only. You write to testData and this must not be done unsynchronised. It is really that dead simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the HTTP server of the standard lib calls handlers on their own goroutine, you must synchronzie access to all variables that are defined outside of the handlers (and where one of the access is a write). You have to do this whenever you use the stdlib's HTTP server. It doesn't matter if you use the standard lib's multiplexer or Gorilla's. The goroutine launch happens outside of the multiplexer (before the multiplexer is called).

Failing to do so (like in your example), data race occurs which you can verify by running it with the `-race` option:

```
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c000090c30 by goroutine 21:
  runtime.mapassign_fast64()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/map_fast64.go:92 +0x0
  main.addData()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:47 +0x191
  net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2007 +0x51
  github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP()
      /home/icza/gows/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.3/mux.go:212 +0x13e
  net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2802 +0xce
  net/http.(*conn).serve()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1890 +0x837

Previous read at 0x00c000090c30 by goroutine 7:
  runtime.mapiternext()
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:851 +0x0
  main.getData()
      /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:32 +0x194
  net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP()
      /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2007 +0x51
...
```